# Install4j - How to uninstall previously packaged app on the Mac that's now a Mac Folder?

Tags: java, macos, installation, install4j

In our previous version the installer type for the Mac OS was "Mac OS X single bundle" however now due to changing needs I am using "Mac OS X folder". The problem is that I need to remove the old application and I can't seem to do it.

I've tried to use the "Uninstall previous Installation" action but this doesn't seem to do anything. And I suspect it has to do with the fact that the installation type has changed.

I then tried to create a "Delete files and directories" action and use:

```
${installer:sys.installationDir}\..\ApplicationName.app
```

where ApplicationName is our application name. However this doesn't seem to be working either. I have set the "File filter script" and "Directory filter script" to `return true;` As well I've check marked "Recursive".

I looked through the folders and also couldn't find an `installation.log` file to use to diagnose the issue.

**Update:** Here are results from the log file (with ApplicationName.app edited):

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 3184]: Execute action
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Property backupForRollback: true
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property showProgress: false
       Property recursive: true
       Property files: [/Applications/LandlordMax/../ApplicationName.app]
       Property directoryFilter: I4jScript_Internal_5
       Property fileFilter: I4jScript_Internal_6
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 3184]: Execute action not successful after 22 ms
```

I see that there is an error for the action, but I can't seem to get any more details. At least nothing to troubleshoot with I have tried to `cd` to the directory by copy and pasting the file location value from the installation.log file and it exists and has content. I can also delete it from the terminal with `rm -rf` and the path.

And the `Action elevation type` is set to `Elevate to maximum priviledges` for that action

Comment: As I assume you'll probably be answering Ingo, I just wanted to let you know I thought this was a better avenue to ask then through support so that others could benefit from it. Thanks :)

Comment: You may check for existance of older app and if it exists, don't install and say to your users to uninstall old one.

Comment: I'd much prefer to automate the process to make it easier on my users. Downloading and installing an application can be challenging for some users, so adding another layer is something I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I agree, posting these kind of problems on SO is indeed a better idea that to handle them through support.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier if it is an app and deals with external documents surely users want OSX to deal with it as an app (e.g. open files when you click on them) not a folder that you would have to run scripts to use

Answer (score 2):

The "Mac OS X single bundle" media type does not have an uninstaller (the user just drags the bundle to the trash bin), so the "Uninstall previous" action will not work.

Using the "Delete file and directories" action is the right idea. Most likely, `${installer:sys.installationDir}\..\ApplicationName.app` does not point to the right directory. The log file is in .install4j/installation.log which is hidden by default, so you either have to use the terminal to navigate to the file, or see [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1051830/showallfinder.html) to show them in the finder.

Comment: I was using terminal but I forgot about hidden files. I almost always just do "ls -al" but for some weird reason looking at the terminal history I kept doing just "ls". Oops. Thank you, that does help a lot.

Comment: Also sorry for all the comments, I've been working hard at this since I'm trying to get a release out this week ;)

Comment: After a lot of debugging I think it has to do with the "/../" in the path, that it's not able to properly resolve that. Because if I hardcode the path, that is "/Applications/ApplicationName.app" then everything is fine. Basically "/Applications/ApplicationName/../ApplicationName.app" works in the terminal but not through the installer.

Comment: It looks like I spoke too soon. The installer doesn't seem to have the permissions to delete the folder, just test to see if it exists if it's hardcoded...

Comment: Do you start the installer as a normal user? In that case, locate the "Request privileges" action in the startup node of your installer and select the  "Try to obtain root privileges if normal user" property in the "Mac OS X" section. Also check that the "Action elevation type" property of the "Delete files ad directories" action is set to "Elevate to maximum available privileges" (this is the default).

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the log file?

Comment: For sure. But I'll have to post it in a few days, we're going ahead with the launch anyways so right now we're extremely under the gun. For now we're asking people to un-install their previous version manually (because we can detect it). But if we can resolve this issue and automatically remove it that would be great, then we can silently update the installer for any new downloads after the initial burst. Thanks Ingo for looking into this. I'll post an update shortly.